# VSCode Extension - TreeView with HTTP Items; Only return when request finished

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to create a VSCode extension for displaying all open issues (data provided by selfhosted gitea). The ChildItemProviderInterface for my TreeView implements two methods. They can't be set to async (at least I couldn't figure out how). I need to return my child array once the HTTP Request finished (thenable)

```
    refresh(): Thenable<vscode.TreeItem[]> {
        axios.get("http://GITURL.com/api/v1/repos/REPOOWNER/REPOSITORY/issues", { headers: { Authorization: "token TOKEN" } }).then(res => {
            let issueList: any[] = [];
            for (const issue of res.data) {
                const title = issue["title"];
                const id = issue["id"];
                const body = issue["body"];
                const state = issue["state"];
                const assignee = issue["assignee"] === null ? "None" : "Username";
                const label = "adf";
                const issueForList = new Issue(title, id, body, state, assignee, label, vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None);
                this.issueList.push(issueForList);
            }
            return this.issueList;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Comment: You simply need to add `return` before `axios.get(...)`

Comment: Type Promise<void | any> is not assignable to type Thenable<vscode.TreeItem[]>

Comment: `Thenable<vscode.TreeItem[]>` => `Thenable<any>`

Comment: Also, add a `async` keyword before `refresh()` will make it async. Yes, it's that easy.

Comment: Axios.get returns a AxiosPromise which is not a thenable<any>. Could you please give me an example if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: For some reason I can not set the returntype to thenable when I use async. When I use await instead of return I only receive the type error but nothing more.